# Print a vector of maps

Tags: c++

how do I print a vector of multimaps?
for example I have a vector that looks like this:

```
typedef std::multimap<double,std::string> resultMap;
typedef std::vector<resultMap> vector_results;
```

**EDIT**

```
for(vector_results::iterator i = vector_maps.begin(); i!= vector_maps.end(); i++)
{
   for(vector_results::iterator j = i->first.begin(); j!= i->second.end(); j++)
   {
      std::cout << j->first << " " << j->second <<std::endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: At least give it a go so we have something to work on where you cannot fix your particular problem.

Comment: @EdHeal: I actually did. here is the try

`for(vector_results::iterator i = vector_maps.begin(); i!= vector_maps.end(); i++){
 for(vector_results::iterator j = i->first.begin(); j!= i->second.end(); j++){
 std::cout << j->first << " " << j->second <<std::endl; 
   }
  
}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pretty-print C++ STL containers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers)

Comment: @AbhiShah - Why not put that into the question.

Comment: @AbhiShah `i` points to a `resultMap`, change the inner for loop to `for( resultMap::iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j )`

Comment: @Praetorian: thanks I tried that and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `i` variable in the outer `for` loop points to a `resultMap`, which means the type of the `j` variable needs to be `resultMap::iterator`. Rewrite your loops as

```
for(vector_results::const_iterator i = vector_maps.begin(); i != vector_maps.end(); ++i)
{
   for(resultMap::const_iterator j = i->begin(); j != i->end(); ++j)
   {
      std::cout << j->first << " " << j->second << std::endl;
   }
}
```

I changed the iterator type to `const_iterator` since the iterators are not modifying the container elements.

---

If your compiler supports C++11's range based `for` loops, the code can be written much more succinctly

```
for( auto const& i : vector_maps ) {
  for( auto const& j : i ) {
    std::cout << j.first << " " << j.second << std::endl;
  }
}
```